# Appending or inserting footnotes programmatically into google doc using google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am using Google App Script to generate a new google doc. The contents of the document come from an array that is looped and paragraph elements are added, or text elements are inserted/appended to pre-existing paragraph elements that were earlier in the loop.

***The issue is: some of the items in the array need to be appended or inserted as footnote elements.***

The documentation says that footnote elements are contained within listItem or paragraph elements. However there does not seem to be a method to insert footnotes programmatically in the same way that other elements can be inserted into paragraphs - such as *appendText()* and *appendHorizontalRule()* etc.

I have not posted any code because I do not know where to begin on this issue. Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: The first paragraph sums up a good place to start.  I'd start there, then come back if you need help with the footnotes after you have the basics working.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow? Is what I'm doing something that google app script was not designed for? I think I do have the 'basics' down. I have used this method to create documents with tables and list elements and it has worked well. I can't find any advice or examples in the documentation to assist in programmatically adding footnotes, also there are no relevant questions on stack overflow either. Do you have any specific places I can begin to look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Apps Script documentation,

> ...there are rules about which types of elements can contain other
>   types. Furthermore, the Document Service in Apps Script can only
>   insert certain types of elements. The tree below shows which elements
>   can be contained by a certain type of element.

More details here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs

Footnote and FootnoteSection elements are not highlighted, which means they can't be inserted programmatically.

Comment: Cheers. Thanks for taking the time to explain. I must have skipped over that line in the docs a few times.

Comment: No worries. I ran into this issue before on one of my projects. Unfortunately, Google doesn't seem to have an advanced service or REST API for Docs.